# C# dotnet not being recognized

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've been trying to run a C# project in Visual Studio and keep getting hit with the error:

`'"dotnet.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

From what I've seen online, several people have managed to fix this by messing around with the SDK or with the 'path' environment variables in Window's System properties tab. The problem is, I have no idea what any of these system settings and specifications do, and I can't get a clear answer.

I can tell that VS isn't able to get dotnet working, so what ideas come to mind to fix this error?

Comment: Can you add some links to the solutions you saw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have `%ProgramFiles%\dotnet\` folder in your PC, that's where the `dotnet.exe` file should be.

If you found none, that mean you have not installed .NET Core SDK/Runtime. As you have VS, I am assuming you are writing some code with it, you should install the SDK from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download).

If you have the folder but still have the problem, [go to your Environment Variable, add that folder to the end of `PATH` variable](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) and restart the PC.

Comment: Your suggestion ended up netting me a fix, thanks man! The site you linked suggests editing the 'Path' System Variable, which I had already tried. So I instead edited the 'PATH' User Variable. I'm not sure if I did something terrible, but it works so at least I can sleep now.

Answer (score 3):

Install the DotNet Core Runtime or SDK (I use latest version)

The SDK has all the tools needed for development (including the runtime), while the Runtime is needed for running dotnet core applications.

After installation, you will need to restart the PC yourself so that the data entered in the PATH variable are available

[Runtime link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2)

Comment: SDK includes the runtime, and given he's running from Visual Studio I'm guessing he might benefit. Also might be worth noting that dotnet.exe is for dotnet core.

Comment: I had to install Runtime separately, and the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the answer from @Luke Vo ended up directing me towards the fix. I appreciate the info on the SDK, however!